# Flash a message when redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added `get "*path", to: "pages#home"` at the bottom of `routes.rb` to catch all the routes that not exist and redirect to `home`. I want to show something like `flash[:warning] = "This pages does not exists."` but I don't know where to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your `home` page.

```
  <% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
    <div>
      <%= msg %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I do display flash messages but I don't know where to generate this message.

Comment: @saralance have u tried smth like this `get "*path", to: redirect("/articles", notice: "Book not found")`

Comment: I tried but it tries to go to `Started GET "/route_not_exists" for ::1 at 2020-08-27 14:05:05 -0300`

Comment: @saralance  my bad its supposed to be `redirect("/", ...)`

Answer (score 0):

It's works for me

```
def home
  return if params[:path].blank?
  
  flash[:alert] = 'This pages does not exists.' 
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the alert as an arg for the redirect_to method

```
redirect_to root_path, alert: 'This pages does not exists.'
```

You can also do it like this, in case you want to try a custom key for the flash hash

```
redirect_to root_path, flash: { alert: 'This pages does not exists.' }
```